# Why are my columns colliding with package paracol?

Tags: spacing, xetex, texstudio, columns, paracol

I am trying to use the package paracol to display the same biblical verses in several languages.  Why are my two columns colliding and how can I prevent this?  Also, as a secondary question, I am using the TeXstudio application; why are the `\end{nthcolumn*}` and `\end{nthcolumn}` commands showing as "unrecognized command"?  The source compiles regardless.  I have enabled `paracol.cwl` in the Completion configuration.  I am not very skilled with Xetex yet so please explain as simply as you can.  Here is my source code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{paracol}

\newcommand{\omission}{\hspace{6pt}$\cdots$\hspace{6pt}}
\newcommand{\at}{\,·\enspace} % Greek ano teleia
\newcommand{\setcoptic}{\noindent\setmainfont{Antinoou}}
\newcommand{\setgreek}{\noindent\setmainfont{GFS Porson}}

\begin{document}
\begin{Large}

\begin{paracol}{2}

    \begin{column}
    \setcoptic
    \omission ⲉⲅⲛⲱ⳯ \omission ⲉⲛ ⲧⲟ\omission ⲟⲩⲧⲟ\at\omission ⲡⲏⲅⲅⲉⲓ\omission ⲉ ⲉⲅⲟ\omission ⲥⲏ\omission
    \end{column}

    \begin{column}
    \setgreek
    καὶ εἶπεν αὐτῷ Ἀβιμέλεχ Οὐκ ἔγνων τίς ἐποίησεν τὸ πρᾶγμα τοῦτο\at οὐδὲ σύ μοι ἀπήγγειλας, οὐδὲ ἐγὼ ἤκουσα ἀλλὰ σήμερον.
    \end{column}

    \begin{nthcolumn*}{0}
    verse 27 goes here
    \end{nthcolumn*}

    \begin{nthcolumn}{1}
    verse 27 goes here
    \end{nthcolumn}

\end{paracol}

\end{Large}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is just standard overfull lines when typesetting in a narrow column. If LaTeX can't find how to break a paragraph into lines with high quality, it *gives up*, outputs a bad line, and displays a warning about it. You don't need to set extra-wide column separation, but instead use the common techniques to permit good line-breaking in paragraphs.

- Ensure hyphenation patterns are loaded for your languages, and *do* select the language in the text -- don't just switch font. I have my doubts about hyphenating ancient coptic.
- Pay attention to "Overfull hbox" warnings in the log file. If they're hard to track down, declare `\setlength\overfullrule{5pt}` to flag the locations in the typeset output. (Remove it for final typesetting.)
- Maybe declare `\sloppy` to allow line breaks that are typically unacceptable. Then LaTeX will give warnings about the lines that are ridiculously stretched out.
- Allow more flexibility in lines. Like with your `\omission` macro, add flexibility to the spacing: `\newcommand{\omission}{\hspace{6ptplus3ptminus3pt}$\cdots$\hspace{6ptplus3ptminus3pt}}`
- Don't force flush margins if the text has trouble fitting. Try

  - `\raggedright`for the most ragged appearance
  - `\RaggedRight` using the ragged2e package for less raggedness
  - `\setlength\rightskip{0pt plus 8pt}` for some raggedness without packages.

Comment: This is definitely the correct answer. The command for ragged2e is `\RaggedRight` but the edit was too minor to submit. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Not too minor to fix! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After reading through the paracol documentation further, I found that setting `\setcolumnwidth{30pt,30pt}` fixed my collision issue. I am not sure if this is the most proper answer and still welcome other answers or an explanation of why this works.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the separation between columns modifying the following parameter:

```
\setlength{\columnsep}{20pt}
```

And this part fixes the justification issue with columns flowing over:

```
\tolerance=1
\emergencystretch=\maxdimen
\hyphenpenalty=10000
\hbadness=10000
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!